# changing a string of numbers into an int from a part of a parsed string

Tags: java, string, parsing

So if I were given a string "Cylinder/soda200/0.0054/5/10" and were to parse it, how would I actually take the parts with just numbers and turn them into an int or double?

Currently I am parsing it by doing this:

```
    String delims="[/]+";
    String[] drinkParse=lineToParse.split(delims);
```

Comment: What is the exact output you would want to have? 200? 200, 0.0054, 5, 10? 200/0.0054?

Comment: `int i = Integer.parseInt(str);`

Comment: I want each number separate, so say 0.0054 would be a double while 5 and 10 would be made an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Integer.parseInt()`, `Double.parseDouble()` etc, passing your string as an argument.

e.g.    `int i = Integer.parseInt(drinkParse[3]);`

Note that these can throw a `NumberFormatException` if the argument can't be parsed as requested. (e.g. "soda200" can't parse straight to an int)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `new Integer("22")` and save it to an `int` in order to convert it.  Same for `Double`.  There are other ways too though, I suggest simple googling.

Answer (score 0):

You should use split function and parse like this

```
Object[] values = (Object[]) var.split("/");
values[2]=Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
values[3]=Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
values[4]=Integer.parseInt(values[4]);
System.out.println(values);
```

You can also iterate array and check if string validates against rege/p of double or int and then do corresponding conversion if you dont know positions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're familiar with `StringBuilder` in java, but you can learn more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and you can also take a look at `String` API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). In the program example below I'm reading character by character from the string you posted until program runs into '/' or unless it's the end of the string. All characters are saved to the `StringBuilder` and converted into a `String` after to check if it's a number, either double or integer. If any character in the string is not a number or period *isNumber* flag value is set to false and we don't print it. In case it's a period we set *isDouble* flag value to true because we need that information for further conversion. At last we print the numbers if all conditions are true and create new `StringBuilder` in order to start building a fresh new `String`.

```
public class myProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Cylinder/soda200/0.0054/5/10";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isDouble;
        boolean isNumber;

        System.out.println("List of numbers:");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            if (str.charAt(i) != '/') {
                sb.append(str.charAt(i));
            }

            if (str.charAt(i) == '/' || i+1 == str.length()) {

                String strConvert = sb.toString();
                isDouble = false;
                isNumber = true;

                for (int j = 0; j < strConvert.length(); j++) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(strConvert.charAt(j))) {
                        if (strConvert.charAt(j) == '.') {
                            isDouble = true;
                        } else {
                            isNumber = false;
                        }                        
                    }
                }

                if (isDouble && isNumber) {
                    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(strConvert));
                } else if (isNumber) {
                    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(strConvert));
                }

                sb = new StringBuilder();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help you or anyone else with similar problem!